# Qual è il significato di "arressarsi"?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel romanzo *Una questione privata* di Beppe Fenoglio ho letto:

> Ma poi uno dei soldati scoppiò in una risata e tutti gli altri lo seguirono a ridere. Poi un altro
>   puntò precipitosamente il dito al ventre della collina piramidale e un paio si buttarono dietro la mitragliatrice.
>   Ma non fecero niente, e dopo un momento **si arressarono** tutti a picchiar sulla schiena quello del dito.

La mia domanda è sul significato di "arressarsi" nell'ultima frase. Non ho trovato questo verbo in nessuno dei dizionari che ho consultato. Più avanti nel libro questo vocabolo appare di nuovo:

> Gli **si arressarono** davanti agli occhi le facce smunte e infantili dei ragazzi fucilati, i loro nudi petti, magri
>   che lo sterno vi sporgeva come una prua.

Sapreste spiegarmi cosa significa "arressarsi"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Non ho mai sentito né letto il verbo “arressare”, ma non è difficile capire che significa, perché è costruito secondo lo schema “fetta > affettare”. Dunque

> fare ressa

nel [senso 2 del Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ressa/)

> Affollamento di gente che preme, che si accalca per entrare, per avvicinarsi, ecc.; la massa stessa di persone che così si affolla.

Comment: "Arressarsi" è sinonimo di "affollarsi", costruito secondo il medesimo schema di "affettare".